# Nativescript Tabview bug when switching between tabs

Tags: nativescript

I've got a tabview with 3 tabs. In the last tab, I've got a BUTTON with tap="{{ myTapEvent }}" set. I get the callback when I tap.

The problem is that if I switch to another tab (e.g. tab #1) and then back to tab #3 and tap on the BUTTON - I get 2 callbacks.

Switch between the tabs N times - when I tap on the BUTTON , I get N callbacks.

So looks like the event is being registered everytime the tab is selected but not being deregistered on selecting another tab.

If this is not the proper place, where do I report this bug.

Comment: hmmm. I use TabView with 5 tabs and a bunch of tap events in each of them, never seen this issue. Could be Label related, try adding the tap event to something else, like a StackLayout or Button. 
Also, how are you adding the tab-views? Directly to the xml, or loading them dynamically via code?

Comment: Actually it's a BUTTON and via xml.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I'm using 2.4 (nativescript core) and do not have this issue.

Comment: Yes it is. It happens only if i switch from tab 3 to 1 and back - not 2 to 1. I think this is because when you switch more than 1 tab away, TabView does internal saving/restoring of state. If you can test it, pls make sure at least 3 tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator error!

I had the following:

```
<Button text="{{ to_date }}" onTap="{{ onDateTap }}"/>
```

The attribute for tap event was **onTap** instead of **tap**.

It does work - but causes the multiple callbacks.